# Polled Consumer With Functional Programming & Stream bridge

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using spring cloud stream with kafka broker for microservice inter-communication. As part of which, `stream bridge` will be used to send the message, which is fine.

**But during consumption of said message, the message need not be immediately consumed, rather when a condition is satisfied, then only, it should be consumed**.

From the documentation, I understand that I need to use `Polled Consumers`(do correct me if I'm mistaken) for this.

This is what I've tried from what I've understood of the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-streams-overview-using-polled-consumers).

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.pollable-source = consumeResponse
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition = consumeResponse

#stream bridge
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outputchannel1.destination = REQUEST_TOPIC
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outputchannel1.binder= kafka1

#polled Consumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumeResponse-in-0.binder= kafka1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumeResponse-in-0.destination = REQUEST_TOPIC
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumeResponse-in-0.group = consumer_cloud_stream1

spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.type=kafka
```

MainApplication.java

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {
        //produce message
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            streamBridge.send("outputchannel1", "msg"+i);
            System.out.println("Request :: " + "msg"+i);
        }
    };
}


@Bean
public Consumer<String> consumeResponse() {
    return (response) -> {
        //consume message
        System.out.println("Response :: " + response);
    };
}


@Bean
public ApplicationRunner poller(PollableMessageSource destIn, MessageChannel destOut) {
    return args -> {
        while (someCondition) { //some condition that checks whether or not to consume the message
            try {
                //condition satisfied, so forward message to consumer
                if (!destIn.poll(m -> {
                    String newPayload = ((String) m.getPayload());
                    destOut.send(new GenericMessage<>(newPayload));
                })) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But this throws the following exception:-

```
Parameter 1 of method poller in com.MainApplication required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - nullChannel: defined in null
    - errorChannel: defined in null
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out here or point me towards a working example for the same.

Spring boot version: 2.6.4,
Spring cloud version: 2021.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just inject the `StreamBridge` into your runner instead of the message channel?

By default, stream bridge output channels are created on-demand (first send).

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delay in response. I'm using `StreamBridge` in one microservice for sending the message. While the polled consumer is used in another microservice for controlling the consumption of the incoming message. I'm not facing any issues while sending the message, it is pushing the message to kafka as expected. The microservice with the polled consumer is facing the issue

Comment: Right; but you are trying to wire in an output message channel bean that doesn't exist yet; the bean will be registered on the first send; use a `StreamBridge` there too. `poller(PollableMessageSource destIn, StreamBridge bridge)`. Alternatively, you can pre-declare the output binding using `spring.cloud.stream.source` https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources '>However, if you want to pre-create an output binding at the initialization...`.